# How can I increment the value in the called function?

Tags: c

How can I pass the pointer to the structure to another function?

sample:

```
#include<stdio.h>

    
struct customer{
char name[50];
int number;
};

void input(){

struct customer details;
   
   printf("enter your name:  ");
   scanf("%s",details.name);
   
   details.number++;
   printf("%d\t%s",details.number,details.name);
}
int main(){
    struct customer details;
    
    input();
    
    //pcust->number++; how should I declare this?
    
    printf("%d\t%s",details.number,details.name);
    
}
```

how do you automatically assign a number in a struct where I can call its value in other functions?

suppose I have this struct

```
struct customer{
char name[50];
int number;
};
```

and request input for the user

```
void input(){

struct customer details;

   printf("enter your name");
   scanf("%s",details.name);

   printf("enter your number");
   scanf("%d",&details.number);
}
```

instead of asking them to enter their number in the function to call it by value, how can I assign it automatically, so I can call it by its value? The possible output I need is like this so that in the next function again, I can call by its value again.

```
1 customer1
2 customer2
....
```

Comment: Logic like that is not automatic. You'd need to keep track of the current number, increment it, and assign it to the new instance.

Comment: Given `char name;` in the structure, using `scanf("%s",details.name);` is simply wrong — you need to provide the address, and you can't store any string in a single character.  Most probably, you need `char name[32];` or something similar (and then you should use `scanf("%31s", details.name)`.  Failing that, `scanf(" %c", &details.name);` where the leading space in the format string is not an accident.  You should also check the return value from each `scanf()` call to check you got what you expected.

Comment: On an unrelated note, when creating a [mre] please make sure it fits the problem you're asking about. If the shown code have other problems (like your have) then it tend to distract from the real issue and the real problem you're asking about. At the very least, try to build it yourself, with extra warnings enabled, and treat all warnings you get as errors that must be fixed. Only show code that doesn't have other unrelated problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll improve my code.

Comment: how can I increment it? 

will it be `int number=0` and `++number;`? But how can I call it by value in another function?

Comment: Have you tried `details.number++` (or `++details.number`)?  If you have passed a pointer to the customer to a function, then `pcust->number++` or `++pcust->number`.  If you don't pass a pointer to the structure to another function, you cannot increment the value in the calling function from the called function.  That is, given `some_function(details);`, `some_function()` cannot change the value in `details.number`.   Only if you pass a pointer, `some_function(&details)`, can `some_function()` change the value in the `details` structure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! I am trying to do what you have said. I posted the code above, but how can I pass a pointer to another function? How can I declare it? Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct customer
{
    char name[50];
    int number;
};

void input(struct customer *pDetails)
{

    printf("enter your name:  ");
    scanf("%s", pDetails->name);

    pDetails->number++;
    printf("%d\t%s \n", pDetails->number, pDetails->name);
}

int main()
{
    struct customer details = {};

    input(&details);

    printf("%d\t%s \n", details.number, details.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your main problem is that you do not use any function parameters.
2. You need to have some kind of search (for example if you want to modify a customer record
3. Use arrays to store multiple data.

Example:

```
struct customer
{
    char name[50];
    int somedata;
};

struct database
{
    size_t size;
    struct customer customers[];
};

struct customer *findCustomer(const struct database *db, const char *name)
{
    struct customer *result = NULL;
    if(db)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < db -> size; i++)
            if(!strcmp(db -> customers[i].name, name))
            {
                result = (struct customer *)&db -> customers[i];
                break;
            }
    }
    return result;
}

struct database *addCustomer(struct database *db, const char *name)
{
    size_t newSize = db ? db -> size + 1 : 1;

    db = realloc(db, newSize * sizeof(db -> customers[0]) + sizeof(*db));
    if(db)
    {
        strcpy(db -> customers[db -> size].name, name);
    }
    return db;
}
```